# Ideas for a SPOJ FISHER

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem on SPOJ:

```
                  http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FISHER/
```

I could not come up with a solution for this one. I found a few threads on topcoder but I could only infer that DP is to be used. It would be very helpful if someone could guide me on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use dynamic programming to solve normal shortest path problems you get http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm. This ignores the time constraint, of course. You can always make a dynamic programming algorithm more flexible - at a cost - by expanding the state space. In this case, instead of keeping track, at each node, of the cost of the cheapest path to that node found so far, you could keep track, for i = 1,2,3,4.. of the cost of cheapest path to the node with time to that node of at most i. You should be able to update this array of costs with a variant of the recursion used to calculate the single cost - each edge relaxation takes a vector of cheapest costs given time and considers adding the time and cost of that edge at each offset to see if the resulting extended path is better than the best known path ending with that edge so far.

I wonder if you could save time by converting Dijkstra's algorithm in a similar way? At the very least you could run Dijkstra's algorithm first, for time, and then discard all nodes with a shortest time path to them longer than your time constraint.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to solve the problem is by using the Dijkstra's algorithm http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/. The constraints are `n<=50` and `time<=1000`. Let time given = T. We thus expand each node into T nodes in which `dist[node][i]` represents the shortest path to node for a given time i. Thus we will be running the algorithm on `n * T` nodes with `n * n * T` edges which will be well within the given time constraints with complexity of `O((n * T + n * n *T) * log( N * T) )`.
My accepted solution: http://ideone.com/H8UUMf

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming.

You only keep track of a path to a node if all paths that take less time than that have higher cost.  When you see a new path you can use a binary search to find the longest time path that is the same time or shorter, and then add the new path only if it costs less than that one, and has not exceeded the time limit.  When you add it, remove all existing paths that take longer and aren't cheaper.

You will finally get an array of paths to the final node that are arranged by time.  Pick the cheapest one that fits in the time constraint.

Note that you probably will want a todo list of nodes to consider, and a node can wind up on that todo list multiple times (it winds back on it every time you find a new cheap path to it.)